# Cocoapods is not available - EAS build for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods, eas

I'm using this command to run eas build for ios locally on my mac.

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios --local
```

But upon running the command, i'm getting the below error:

```
Cocoapods is not available, make sure it's installed and in your PATH
pod exited with non-zero code: 1
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
```

I've cocoapods installed. Tried running `pod --version`. It shows 1.12.1

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Even `which pod` returned me a path.
Try with:

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```